# Undefined constant error with SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, soap, salesforce

I recently spun up a new server on digital ocean and have set it up to work with laravel. Everything is working up to this point.

I am utilizing a Salesforce package which is throwing the error:

```
Exception at ConstructorUse of undefined constant SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS - assumed 'SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS'\n
```

Looking into the soap docs, SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS is part of it so naturally I have installed the php soap package, but that does not seem to have done the trick. What could I be missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: Same question ^

Comment: solved, see below

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and realized that php-soap was not installed.

Did a quick `apt-get install php5.6-soap` and everything worked normally. Change appropriately for your version